# Git shell style not colorized as in Powershell on windows 7

Tags: shell, powershell, github, windows-7, github-for-windows

I've installed `Github` on `Windows 7 (64bits)` but the `Git Shell` is not taking the style of `Powershell` (white font on a blue background).

This is how the `Git shell` looks like:
[image: Git Shell]

And this is the `Powershell` (how the `Git Shell` is supposed to look like):
[image: PowerShell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you open PowerShell determines the appearance. If you open it from the Start Menu, you get the customized appearance from settings on that shortcut. Ex:
[image]

If you open PowerShell directly from the executable, it has no customizations. Ex:
[image]

If you go to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 and open the powershell.exe directly and customize the settings, it should stay. If Git's opening PowerShell using a different shortcut, find and customize that. Ex:
[image]